# select multiple record email of my grid view to send email

Tags: yii

I have a CGridView with a CCheckBoxColumn. Users can select multiple rows of my grid view.  The gridview is for a list of email and I want to be able to select email from the grid, hit "Send mail" button to send the mail for selected email id.

Answer (score 0):

Here is nothing special. Just enclose your grid in `form`, add `submit` button and process checked items in controller to which the form is submitted.